# How can I test the request object using a specific URL in application_helper_spec.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec2, helper

I have a method defined in application_helper.rb that returns a canonical URL based on the current request. How can I mock or otherwise specify a complete URL for the controller?

```
# spec/helpers/application_helper_spec.rb
describe "#canonical_url" do
  it "should return a path to an asset that includes the asset_host" do
    # Given: "http://www.foo.com:80/asdf.asdf?asdf=asdf"
    helper.canonical_url().should eq("http://www.foo.com/asdf.asdf")
  end
end

# app/helpers/application_helper.rb
def canonical_url
  "#{request.protocol}#{request.host}#{(request.port == 80) ? "" : request.port_string}#{request.path}"
end
```

**EDIT**:

Ultimately I want to test that canonical_url() returns the proper string for a bunch of different URLs, some with ports, some w/o, some with querystrings, some with paths, etc. Maybe that's overkill, but that is the end goal. I would like to both explicitly stub/mock/whatever the initial URL and then explicitly set the expectation in the matcher. I would love to be able to do this in one call, i.e. `controller.request.url = 'http://www.foo.com:80/asdf.asdf?asdf=asdf'` or `request = ActionController::TestRequest.new :url => 'http://www.foo.com:80/asdf.asdf?asdf=asdf'` but so far I have not found a single "hook" that allows me to do so. So that is the solution I'm looking for. **How do I explicitly define the request URL for a given test.**

Comment: PS: I really don't care what the URL is that I pass in. It doesn't need to be the applications own URL because the canonical_url method should work for any given URL. However, I **do** want to explicitly define it before the test and not rely on what the ActionController::TestRequest defaults to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd have done:

```
helper.request.stub(:protocol).and_return("http://")
helper.request.stub(:host).and_return("www.foo.com")
helper.request.stub(:port).and_return(80)
helper.request.stub(:port_string).and_return(":80")
helper.request.stub(:path).and_return("/asdf.asdf")
helper.canonical_url.should eq("http://www.foo.com/asdf.asdf")
```

Comment: I had tried a variant of that, but using `controller.request.mock(:protocol) { 'http://' }` and got an error saying that mock was undefined on the request object. I can try it again using your example, but I would really love to just set it as a single string just before each test is run.

Comment: I was about to complain that this approach doesn't work after all because the querystring portion that I want to have stripped isn't specified anywhere. But that is ideally left up to Rails internals IRL and `#path` should return only the path w/o the querystring anyways. So, you are correct. Sometimes I run past the "that's the framework's job" line and don't realize it.

Comment: *Still*... I would like to know if there is a way to just specify the URL all at once.

Comment: A priori, I can't see anyway to achieve that. But I'll keep the question in mind

Answer (score 2):

The ultimate cause of this confusion lies in ActionPack:

- ActionDispatch::TestRequest
- ActionDispatch::Http::URL

e.g. if you set a port (ActionDispatch::TestRequest)

```
def port=(number)
  @env['SERVER_PORT'] = number.to_i
end
```

e.g. then you read it (ActionDispatch::Http::URL)

```
def raw_host_with_port
  if forwarded = env["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST"]
    forwarded.split(/,\s?/).last
  else
    env['HTTP_HOST'] || "#{env['SERVER_NAME'] || env['SERVER_ADDR']}:#{env['SERVER_PORT']}"
  end
end
```

Setting SERVER_PORT will only take effect if you have no SERVER_NAME, HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST or HTTP_HOST already set.

My basic workaround for port settings was to add the port to the host - because request.port doesn't do what you want typically.

e.g. to set the port

```
request.host = 'example.com:1234'
```

The real answer is to read the code in ActionPack; it's fairly straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up answer. I will try this approach next time.

Answer (score 0):

Very late to this party, but found it googling something similar.

How about:

```
allow_any_instance_of(ActionController::TestRequest).to receive(:host).and_return('www.fudge.com')
```

I appreciate `allow_any_instance_of` is sometimes frowned upon, but this does seem to get the job done.